# If two functions are always equal a.e. in one argument, are they always equal a.e. in the other argument?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose we have two Lebesgue measurable functions:
$$
f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \qquad
g: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
such that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the functions
$$
f(x, \_): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \qquad
g(x, \_): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
are almost-everywhere equal by the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it the case that for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ the functions:
$$
f(\_, y): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \qquad
g(\_, y): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
are also almost-everywhere equal by the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The partial functions are continuous and ae equal, so they are equal.

Comment: you are correct. I asked the wrong question.

Comment: I have edited the question @SolubleFish

Comment: You're given a statements that are true for almost-every $y$ and you're asked to prove something for every $y$, so that's going to present a problem.

Comment: Try picking a particular $y$ that "messes things up". One value of $y$ will not affect the truth of statements about almost-every $y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. For example, let $f(x,y)=0$ identically, and let
$
g(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if }y=0, \\ 0, &\text{if }y\ne0.
\end{cases}
$